# How to polish curving edges?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, workflow, edges, sculpting

I have 2 questions please:
1. Just wondering how to polish these edges and make it look clean? And make it look more like hard edges.
2. I'm not satisfied with how the curve looks. I'm using snake tools to create it.

[image: These two things]

[image: Curves that I wanted to create]

Curves that I wanted to create

Answer (score 1):

The Grab brush (Shortcut "G") is great for getting the right shape for your curve.

What I'd use here would be the Fill/Deepen brush (shortcut "5") and the Flatten brush (shortcut "6"). Then I'd gently smooth the flat surfaces until close to the hard edge (shortcut "Shift").

If there's any edge that I was completely happy with, the pinch brush (Shortcut "P") is great for getting a sharper edge to finish it off.

Just play around with strength and keep undoing things if you make mistakes.

Sculpting these harder surfaces takes a bit of practise but it's generally the fastest way.

OR

If you don't feel comfortable with this, perhaps you could try retopologising it using a shrink wrap modifier and a vertex group. This way you can remove certain vertices from the shrinkwrap vertex group and play with a specific vertex until you're happy. With your retopologised mesh, you can play with the Mean Crease in properties panel ("N") underneath the transform data to get those edges nice a crisp when applying a subdivision surface.

Comment: just tried your suggestion, I think I need more practice. Still struggling to get it clean and smooth. But I haven't tried to retopologised it yet.

Comment: Yea sculpting is a skill but a skill I think everyone can improve over time, however, what I generally do is to model the shape out as much as I can before I start adding detail to it if I think it’s a difficult shape to model like yours could be for example. Like toes and fingers. Hard edges tend to be modelled by most people and bezier curves were really designed for this type of shape. However, I think with a shrinkwrap modifier you could retopologise this into a more refined version. Good luck with it! :)